# StructureMap to Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, structuremap

I need to convert StructureMap code to Ninject (to support my hosting provider because they only support Applications operating under a Medium trust).
basic register that i have in StructureMap is:

```cs
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IDbConnection>()
     .HttpContextScoped()
     .Use(() =>
     {
        var constr = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;                
        var conn = new SqlConnection(constr);        
        conn.Open();        
        return conn;
     });

    x.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IDbConnection>();
    x.For<ICurrent>().Use<Current>();
    x.For<ILogger>().Use<Logger>();
    x.For<IMembershipService>().Use<SpaceMembership>();
    x.For<IFormsAuthenticationService>()
        .Use<FormsAuthenticationService>();
    x.Scan(sc =>
    {
        sc.Assembly("Space360.DB");
        sc.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>));
        sc.WithDefaultConventions();
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured out that X.For<I>.Use<C> can be converter into Ninject Bind<I>().To<C>(); but my problem now is for IDBConnection and also fillAll properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look similar to this:

```
// IDbConnection binding
Bind<IDbConnection>().ToMethod(x => {
                          var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
                          var conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
                          conn.Open();
                          return conn;})
                     .InRequestScope();

// ommited fill all properties of type

Bind<ICurrent>().To<Current>(); // .InRequestScope() - just suggestion
Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>();
Bind<IMembershipService>().To<SpaceMembership>();
Bind<IFormsAuthenticationService>().To<FormsAuthenticationService>();

// for this: Ninject.Extensions.Conventions has to be referenced
Bind(x=> x.From("Space360.DB")
          .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IRepository>()
          .BindDefaultInterface()
       // .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope())
     );
```

I'm afraid that there is currently no built in version of method similar to `FillAllPropertiesOfType` in Ninject. You will have to mark all your dependent properties with `[Inject]` attribute (but it will tie your classes to `Ninject.Core`) or you can try the approach described in this article:

[Ninject 3.0 Property Injection Without [Inject] Attribute](http://jarrettmeyer.com/blog/2012/05/18/ninject-30-property-injection-without-inject-attribute)

Basically it creates Ninject component, implementaion of `IInjectionHeuristic`, which is wired up to ninject kernel so it knows how to interpret the heuristic. The rules for injection in `ShouldInject` method are:

1. The property is a public, writeable property on a class being generated by Ninject
2. It is located in an assembly that we personally care about
3. IT can be resolved

---

For the last line from my example you will need to use [ninject.extensions.conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions)

*Note, tha there is also [ninject.extensions.logging](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging) for implicit injection of logger (currently is supported Log4Net and NLog).*